# PLSQL-database event Trigger

Tags: plsql

Assume  a schema named 'SD' with 100 tables, 25 procedures, etc. The creation of a trigger that will inform me of the modifications (if)made in procedures,  the logging on/off of other users etc is feasible ?
if yes, how can i trace the changes in the code of an existing procedure, the creation/drop of table ?

the trigger 'logon' below inserts in a log file (= table log_events) the users that log on:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER logon
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA
BEGIN 
 INSERT INTO log_events (used_id,log_date,action)
 VALUES (USER,SYSDATE, 'Log on');
END;

--log_events: 
CREATE TABLE log_events ( user_id VARCHAR2(50), log_date DATE, action VARCHAR2(50))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't DDL event triggers work for you? E.g. a trigger `AFTER CREATE OR MODIFY OR DROP` should fire once a table or a procedure is changed.

Comment: The DDL event triggers work, but in case of monitoring the modifications in schema i.e. a newly inserted table or a modified procedure, i need to create triggers per tables or procedures.... or a compound trigger can serve my purpose?

Comment: AFAICT, such a trigger is declared `ON SCHEMA` and if fired on any relevant schema events, that is, when a new table is created or an existing procedure is modified, etc. At least, [so the docs say](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm#sthref7935). Alas, I never used these in real life, and I don't even have an Oracle installation nearby to check it.